# Populate Combobox from a pre-stored parametriced Access-Query

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010

I'm workin with a MS Access 2010 database. I need a combobox to show the result of a sql SELECT sentence but this time my sql sentence is to long to be asigned to the RowSource property of the combobox.

To solve the problem I have created an accesss-query and stored it in the access database queries section with a name like "myQuery". It's sql code is something similar but much longer than the following query:

```
PARAMETERS [myParameter] Long;  
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM [myTable]
WHERE [myTable]![FieldN] = [myParameter]
```

As you can see, the query has a parameter.

Once I created the query I changed the VB code like this:

```
Me.myCombo.RowSource = "myQuery" 'The name of the query I created before
Me.myCombobox.Requery            'Execute the query to populate the combobox
```

It works fine but before each execution MS-Access shows a pop-up window asking for the value of the parameter.

¿How can I avoid this pop-up window and asign or bind a value to the parameter each time a new population is needed? Something like

```
Me.myCombo.RowSource = "myQuery" 'The name of the query I created before
Me.myCombobox.RowSource.Parameters("[myParameter]") = Me.formField1.Value 
Me.myCombobox.Requery            'Execute the query to populate the combobox
```

Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Since your parameter is based on a field in the form, I'd just replace the parameter in the query with a direct reference to the form field.

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM [myTable]
WHERE [myTable]![FieldN] = [Forms]![FormName]![formField1]
```